# What does this notation mean in C?

Tags: c, pointers

```
int *w;
int **d;

d = &w;
```

What does the **d store exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the assignment, `**d` is the same as `*w`.  `d` is a pointer to a pointer to an integer; the pointer to an integer that it points to is `w`.  So `*d` is `w`, and `**d` is `*w`.

Comment: No, `**d` is *not* the same as `*w` -- at least they do not have the same values. Although I think I know what you mean to say (they both ultimately point to the same variable, I think that's slightly misleading.

Comment: @Noldorin, care to point to the C++ standards documentation which states that a dereferenced pointer is not the same value as the memory it points to?

Comment: I think this answer is confusing, since it talks about the dereferencing operator, but the original code did not dereference anything.  The pointer declaration qualifier happens to use the same * glyph. I believe that is what Noldrin is referring to. The two declarations are not equivalent, dereferencing d twice is however the same as dereferencing w once, but I don't believe that that is a useful answer in this context and wonder that it was marked 'accepted'.

Comment: @Franci: I think you're misunderstanding my comment. Also, we're talking about C here, not C++. :)
@Clifford: That's exactly what I'm referring to... I agree this answer creates confusion around the matter. If the OP is reading this, I urge you to at least read my answer or Jack Lloyd's (which is essentially correct).

Comment: Just for this fragment of code, if you deference `**d`, you may get segmentation fault or something garbage integer value as `w` was never initialized properly .

Answer (score 3):

`int **` represents 'a pointer to a pointer to an `int`' (also known as a double pointer).

Now, `int *w` simply represents a pointer to an `int`, thus the assignment `d = &w` is saying: "assign the address of `w` (which is itself a pointer/address) to `d`".

Answer (score 3):

The value of **d is the same as the value of *w; *d is equal to the pointer value saved in w; because d is a pointer to a pointer to an int, you have to dereference it twice to get the actual value.

Answer (score 3):

w stores the address of an int. d stores the address of a pointer to int (except in this case it stores a random value because it doesn't get assigned), in this case the address of d.

Answer (score 0):

**d is a pointer to a pointer to an int, so **d would have the address of the pointer *w, when u say d=&w, but unless u have said that d=&w and just stated 
int *w
int **d, it would have no meaning except for:
int *w is a pointer to an int and int **d is a pointer to a pointer to an int, but in no way it would have stated that d will store the addres of w.